# R: Force data.table to compute all interactions

Tags: r, combinations, data.table, combinatorics, interaction

Here is a data.table:

```
dat = data.table(var1=rnorm(120), var2=rep(c('a','b','c'),40), var3=rep(c(1,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2),10))

dat2 = dat[,list(resp = mean(var1)),by=list(var2, var3)]
```

In `dat2`, only existing interactions of `dat$var2` et `dat$var3` are present. How can I force `dat2` to contain results for all 9 possible interactions (instead of the 7 rows of `dat2`) for `var2` and `var3`? If there is no direct solutions with data.table, what is the easiest way to solve this issue?

```
table(dat$var2, dat$var3)

     1  2  3
  a 20 10 10
  b 20 20  0
  c  0 30 10
```

Of course, for the interactions where no data exist in `dat`, `dat2` should contain NA in resp.

Comment: Why not just do `data.table(...)` instead of `as.data.table(data.frame(...))`?

Comment: No reason, that was dumb! I fixed it! Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set the `key` and then do a crossjoin using `CJ` in the `i` like so...

```
setkey( dat , var2 , var3 )

# Thanks to @Shadow for pointing out to use unique() in the cross join
dat[ CJ( unique(var2) , unique(var3) ) , mean(var1) ]
#   var2 var3          V1
#1:    a    1 -0.25771923
#2:    a    2  0.04143057
#3:    a    3  0.28878451
#4:    b    1  0.18865887
#5:    b    2  0.53632552
#6:    b    3          NA
#7:    c    1          NA
#8:    c    2  0.38015021
#9:    c    3  0.49809159
```

And by way of explanation, `CJ()` creates a `data.table` in the `i` of `x` (in this case `dat`) to join on. It is formed as the cross product of the vectors supplied to `CJ()`, which happens to be precisely what you are looking for!

Comment: I agree that the `CJ` version makes more sense than the `expand.grid` one I suggested below. But for generalizability I still think that `dat[CJ(unique(var2),unique(var3)), mean(var1)]` would be more appropriate than explicitly using `letters[1:3]` and `1:3`.